# Convert DOC with macro to DOTM

Tags: powershell, ms-word, office-interop, office-automation

I am trying to convert DOC files with macros to DOTM with macros. My code changes the files but after the marco section is totally broken. When I convert it manually my macro code stays.

My code is:

```
function ReleaseRef ($ref) {
    if($ref){
        ([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject(
            [System.__ComObject]$ref) -gt 0) 
        [System.GC]::Collect() 
        [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers() 
    }
}

function Convert-DOC{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$filepath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$filefilter
    )

    try {

        $files = Get-ChildItem $filepath -Include "$filefilter" -recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and ( $_.Extension -like "$filefilter") }
        $totalfiles = $files.Count
        [int]$currentfile = 0
        Write-Host "converting files... [$totalfiles]"

        #word object********************************
        #load dotnet assembly
        Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
        #create word object
        $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application -Verbose:$false
        $word.visible = $true
        $word.DisplayAlerts = [Microsoft.Office.InterOp.Word.WdAlertLevel]::wdAlertsNone


        foreach ($file in $files) {
            #Current file number
            [int]$currentfile = [int]$currentfile + 1
            #Check for password
            $catch = $false
            try {
                #open file
                Write-Host $file
                $worddoc = $word.Documents.Open($file.FullName, $null, $null, $null, "")
            } catch {
                #if error, file has password
                Write-Host "$file is protected by Password, skipping..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
                $catch = $true
                continue
            }
            if ($catch -eq $false) {
                try {
                    #**********convert file**********
                    write-host "converting " $file.fullname "file $currentfile of $totalfiles" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
                    #check for links
                    if([IO.Path]::GetExtension($file) -eq ".doc"){
                        #check for macros in in file
                        if ($worddoc.HasVBProject) {
                            $doFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
                            $newfile = ($file.fullname).substring(0, ($file.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
                            $newfile += ".docm"
                        } else {
                            $doFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.XlFileFormat]::wdFormatXMLDocument
                            $newfile = ($file.fullname).substring(0, ($file.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
                            $newfile += ".docx"
                        }
                    }

                    #save file
                    if(Test-Path $newfile){
                        Write-host "$newfile already exists" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                    } else {
                        $worddoc.SaveAs($newfile, $doFixedFormat )
                    }
                    #close file
                    $worddoc.close()
                    Write-Host "done" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen

                    #**********Garbage Collector**********
                    $gc_int++
                    if([int]$gc_int -gt 5){
                        Write-Host 'Run Garbage Collector' -ForegroundColor DarkBlue -BackgroundColor White
                        [System.GC]::Collect()
                        [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
                        [int]$gc_int = 0
                    }
                } catch {
                    $formatstring = "{0} : {1}`n{2}`n" +
                        "    + CategoryInfo          : {3}`n" +
                        "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : {4}`n" +
                        "    + Filename              : {5}`n"
                    $fields = $_.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name,
                        $_.ErrorDetails.Message,
                        $_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage,
                        $_.CategoryInfo.ToString(),
                        $_.FullyQualifiedErrorId,
                        $file.fullname

                    Write-Host -Foreground Red -Background Black ($formatstring -f $fields)
                    "$fields" | Out-File ($scriptpath + '\error_convert.log') -Append
                }
        }
    }

    } finally {
        #**********clean-up************
        Write-Host ""
        Write-Host "Cleaning Up" -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta
        Write-Host "Quiting Word"
        $word.Quit()
        Write-Host "Garbage Collector"
        [gc]::collect()
        [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        Write-Host "Release Com Object Workbook"
        $a = ReleaseRef($worddoc)
        Write-Host "Release Com Object Word"
        $a = ReleaseRef($word)
        Write-Host "Finishing Clean-Up"
    }

}

Convert-DOC -filepath "C:\_testmacro\" -filefilter "*.doc"
```

What I do is, checking if the file has a VB part and is so setting the extension:

```
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
```

and then save it:

```
$worddoc.SaveAs($newfile, $doFixedFormat)
```

A similar function with XLS and XLAM works fine

---

Edit:
seems like I was missing a $worddoc.Convert() but now struggling with checkin/checkout

Comment: What is the actual arguments passed to the `SaveAs` method?

Comment: Where and when do you run the code? Is it run from a service?

Comment: The saveas part is under #save file and I run it as user

Comment: Actual arguments passed to the `SaveAs` method?

Comment: as I said, the file is saved but afterwards the Macro is broken

Comment: What do you mean saying `Macro is broken`?

Answer (score 0):

As my edit stated, I missed the convert command:

```
$worddoc.Convert()
$worddoc.SaveAs($newfile, $doFixedFormat)
```

before saving